# CSS selector does not work correctly

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am using the code

```
footer h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
  color: #fff;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
```

to select all h tags that are inside footer. There's a HTML tag footer and if I'm not mistaken, my code should select only those h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 tags that are inside a footer tag. But surprisingly, when I test my code, it selects all other h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 tags that are outside of the footer tag as well!

How's that possible? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: footer h1,footer h2,footer h3,footer h4,footer h5,footer h6

Comment: so repeat footer as many time as h

Comment: Wow. Guys, you're fast! And thanks for the help, I wouldn't have guessed the issue on my own even if I had looked at the code for hours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
footer h1, footer h2, footer h3, footer h4, footer h5, footer h6{
 color: #fff;
 margin: 10px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to write footer before all h. So that this `css` is implement to footer h1,h2 ... 
like below

```
footer h1, footer h2, footer h3, footer h4, footer h5, footer h6 {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
```